# Trying to use an onClick attribute in html to switch class but not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Hi so I'm trying to get my navBar to work so that when I click it changes the class from item to item active and vice versa for any other active item, at the moment I cannot see where I'm going wrong.  Beginner programmer here so sorry if it's obvious!

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<a href="#about_me" class="item active" onClick="switch(this);">
  About me
</a>
<a href="#experience" class="item" onClick="switch(this);">
  Experiences
</a>
<a href="#education" class="item" onClick="switch(this);">
  Education
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function switch(x) {
  var className = x.getAttribute("class");
  if(className == "item") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("item active").className("item");
    x.className = "item active";
  }
  else {
    x.className = "item";
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: switch is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, you can use another name for your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch` is reserved keyword, you should not use as function name, change to something else like below

```
<a href="#about_me" class="item active" onClick="switchClass(this);">
    About me
</a>
<a href="#experience" class="item" onClick="switchClass(this);">
    Experiences
</a>
<a href="#education" class="item" onClick="switchClass(this);">
    Education
</a>
<script>

    function switchClass(x) {
        if(document.getElementsByClassName("item active").length){
            document.getElementsByClassName("item active")[0].className = "item";
        }
        x.className = "item active";
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some syntax errors you could find if open a console (F12).

- `switch` is reserved keyword
- List item `getElementsByClassName` returns `NodeList`
- `className("item");` is not a function

If you need to toggle current element `active` class you could use `classList.toggle` method.

If you need to "deactivate" rest as well you could use `document.querySelectorAll('.item.active')` combined with `forEach` loop.

```
function deactivate() {
   [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.item.active'), function(el) {
     el.classList.remove('active')
   })
}
```

```js
function toggle(el) {
  el.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#about_me" class="item active" onClick="toggle(this);">
  About me
</a>
<a href="#experience" class="item" onClick="toggle(this);">
  Experiences
</a>
<a href="#education" class="item" onClick="toggle(this);">
  Education
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, switch is a reserved word you can't use it as a function name. Then className is not a method, its a property and can be set.

```js
function switch1(x) {
  var className = x.getAttribute("class");
  if(className == "item") {
    x.className = "item active";
  }
  else {
    x.className = "item";
  }
  return true
}
```

```html
<a href="#about_me" class="item active" onClick="switch1(this);">
  About me
</a>
<a href="#experience" class="item" onClick="switch1(this);">
  Experiences
</a>
<a href="#education" class="item" onClick="switch1(this);">
  Education
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @OscarLingard you are welcome, consider upvoting and accepting answer, if it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Sample Code </title>
  <style>
        .active{
         color:red;
         border:1px solid red;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   
<a href="#about_me" class="item active" onClick="highlight(this)">
  About me
</a>
<a href="#experience" class="item" onClick="highlight(this)">
  Experiences
</a>
<a href="#education" class="item" onClick="highlight(this)">
  Education
</a>



   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       function highlight(el){
           $('.item').removeClass('active');
           $(el).addClass('active');
       }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jquery would make things much simple try this code

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .active {
            color: red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#about_me" id="about_me" class="item active" onClick="switcH('about_me')">
    About me
</a>
<a href="#experience" id="experience" class="item" onClick="switcH('experience')">
    Experiences
</a>
<a href="#education" id="education" class="item" onClick="switcH('education')">
    Education
</a>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function switcH(id) {

        $(".item").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $('#'+id).addClass('active');


    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```